# Systemd file in ubuntu is not behaving as expected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-kafka

I am setting up a kafka cluster on a single machine for that I made 5 copies of kafka and applied configuration accordingly. Now, I want to start and stop each zookeeper individually by using systemd file for that I made copies of systemd files and configured them as below. Now the problem I am facing is when I am trying to stop one instance of zookeeper it is stopping all zookeepers. Why is it behaving like that and how i need to configure systemd file?

**First zookeeper systemmd file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target[Unit]
```

**Second zookeeper systemmd file:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache Zookeeper server1
Documentation=http://zookeeper.apache.org
Requires=network.target remote-fs.target
After=network.target remote-fs.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/kafka_1/bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh /usr/local/kafka_1/config/zookeeper.properties
ExecStop=/usr/local/kafka_1/bin/zookeeper-server-stop.sh
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target[Unit]
```

Remaining systemd files are also similar with only path difference.

Comment: Maybe you provide a link or code to shell scripts and properties file used

Comment: systemd... Not SystemMd

Answer (score 1):

You don't need copies of the whole installation folders. You also shouldn't run more than one of Kafka or Zookeeper on the same machine since you still have a **single point of failure**, whether that's a disk or network interface

Especially, since it's unclear if you've modified any of the default storage directories

Note: if you install Confluent Platform using APT, it comes with its own SystemD scripts